# Troubles with controlP5 and creating objects

Tags: java, object, listbox, controls

I have a menu system that displays different types of objects that can be drawn on the screen.

So basically I have the menu being displayed, then when you click on an option it calls a function called newShape() where it notes down the type of object and gives it an initial position.

Then when draw() is looped it will call a function called drawShapes() which will use the values from an array and create the object the user clicked on. It will then follow the users mouse pointer until it has been clicked.

The code is split up into 3 files, to make it neat.

**Main File**

```
import processing.opengl.*;

void setup(){
  size(500,500,OPENGL);
  background(255);
  setupMenu();
}

void draw(){
  background(255);
  fill(0);
  drawShapes();
}
```

**Menu File**

```
import controlP5.*;

ControlP5 cp5;
ListBox l;
String CI[] = {"Box", "Sphere", "Ellipsoid", "Toroid", "Text"};

void setupMenu() {

  cp5 = new ControlP5(this);
  l = cp5.addListBox("createList")
         .setPosition(0,16)
         .setSize(120, 120)
         .setItemHeight(15)
         .setBarHeight(15)
         .setColorBackground(color(40, 128))
         .setColorActive(color(255, 128))
         ;

  l.captionLabel().toUpperCase(true);
  l.captionLabel().set("Create Item");
  l.captionLabel().setColor(0xffff0000);
  l.captionLabel().style().marginTop = 3;
  l.valueLabel().style().marginTop = 3;


  for (int i = 0; i < CI.length; i++){
    ListBoxItem lbi = l.addItem(CI[i], i);
    lbi.setColorBackground(0xffff0000);
  }

}

void controlEvent(ControlEvent theEvent) {

  if(theEvent.isGroup() && theEvent.name().equals("createList")){
    int Choice = (int)theEvent.group().value();    
    newShape(Choice);
  }
}
```

**Draw Shape File**

```
 int ob = 0;
 int Type[];
 float Pos[][];
 boolean posSet[];

void newShape(int c){
  Type[ob] = c;
  Pos[ob][0] = mouseX;
  Pos[ob][1] = mouseY;
  posSet[ob] = false;
  ob++;
}

void drawShapes(){
  for (int i = 0; i < ob; i++){
    switch(Type[ob]){

      case 0: {
        if (posSet[ob] == false){
          box(Pos[ob][0],Pos[ob][1], 50);
          }
         else {
           box(mouseX,mouseY, 50); break;
         }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT: Should also add the error code...

```
30/05/2012 9:57:09 AM controlP5.ControlBroadcaster printMethodError
SEVERE: An error occured while forwarding a Controller event, please check your code at controlEvent
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at         sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at controlP5.ControlBroadcaster.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
at controlP5.ControlBroadcaster.broadcast(Unknown Source)
at controlP5.ListBox.controlEvent(Unknown Source)
at controlP5.Controller.broadcast(Unknown Source)
at controlP5.Button.setValue(Unknown Source)
at controlP5.Button.activate(Unknown Source)
at controlP5.Button.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at controlP5.Controller.setMousePressed(Unknown Source)
at controlP5.ControllerGroup.setMousePressed(Unknown Source)
at controlP5.ControllerGroup.setMousePressed(Unknown Source)
at controlP5.ControlWindow.mouseReleasedEvent(Unknown Source)
at controlP5.ControlWindow.mouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at processing.core.PApplet$RegisteredMethods.handle(Unknown Source)
at processing.core.PApplet.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at processing.core.PApplet.dequeueMouseEvents(Unknown Source)
at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(Unknown Source)
at processing.core.PApplet.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at Main.newShape(Main.java:43)
at Main.controlEvent(Main.java:104)
... 25 more
```

Answer (score 0):

have you checked if

```
int Type[];
```

inside your Draw Shape File ins not `null` when calling `newShape(int)`?

Comment: Do you mean the variable passed to Type[]? That comes up correctly.

Comment: Hmm I tried to manually assign a value (-1) to Type[0] and I'm getting this error...

processing.app.SketchException: unexpected token: [
 at processing.mode.java.JavaBuild.preprocess(JavaBuild.java:326)
 at processing.mode.java.JavaBuild.preprocess(JavaBuild.java:197)
 at processing.mode.java.JavaBuild.build(JavaBuild.java:156)
 at processing.mode.java.JavaBuild.build(JavaBuild.java:135)
 at processing.mode.java.JavaMode.handleRun(JavaMode.java:176)
 at processing.mode.java.JavaEditor$20.run(JavaEditor.java:481)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the problem was that the array was not initialized.

```
int Type[];
```

Should have been...

```
int[] Type = new int[size];
```

I didn't know what size I needed for the array... so I just put a large value in. Here is the code for all the declarations...

```
int ob = 0, maxShapes = 300, currentShape;
int[] Type = new int[maxShapes];
float[][] Pos = new float[maxShapes][maxShapes];
boolean[] posSet = new boolean[maxShapes];
```